# Capture MediaPlayerPlaying event of VLC Webplugin

Tags: javascript, events, vlc, libvlc

I'm using VLC Webplugin on Chrome

```
<div id="div-vlc" style="display: none;">
    <embed id="vlc" name="vlc" width="640" height="480" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" />
    <object style="width:0px;height:0px;" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">    </object>
</div>
```

And try to catch events to control the play with that:

```
document.vlc.addEventListener('MediaPlayerPlaying', function() {alert();} )
```

or

```
document.vlc.attachEvent('MediaPlayerPlaying', function() {alert();} ) //crash
```

Like this documentation say: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin

But the event is never fired.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to advice about a weird thing ASP.NET does to VLC when dinamically loaded.

ASP.NET returns to the browser wrong width and height attributes in the ActiveX when specific width and height is set in pixels in the aspx.cs or ascx.cs. Sample:

aspx.cs or ascx.cs file:

```
myLiteral.Text = @"<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin'  
width='150px' height='100px'  
pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' events='True' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'>Check activex settings</object>";
```

html returned when client is IE8 or greater:

```
<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin'  
width=0px height=0px style='HEIGHT:0px;WIDTH:0px;TOP:0px;LEFT:0px'  pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' events='True' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'>Check activex settings</object>
```

In IE8 and IE9 it happens only in the first VLC ActiveX. In IE10 it happens in all the VLC ActiveX.

My workaround is a bit of JQuery in my VLC loading javascript:

```
$(plugin).width(playerWidth);
$(plugin).height(playerHeight);
$(plugin).attr('style', '');
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, The info in https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/ is outdated in later versions.

The codebase URL 'http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab' does not exist anymore...

The following has worked fine for me:

```
<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' id='vlc1' width='100px' height='150px' events='True' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'>
    <param name='MRL' value='' />
    <param name='toolbar' value='false' />
    <param name='autoplay' value='false' />
    <param name='loop' value='false' />
    <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true' />
ActiveX not loaded. Check IE settings</object>
```

Javascript:

```
var plugin = document.getElementById('vlc1');
$(plugin).width(playerWidth);
$(plugin).height(playerHeight);
$(plugin).attr('style', '');
// Add items to plugin.playlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- First of all it will not work if you will make it "display:none".
- Secondly there has to be a src/target in embed.
- Last but not least, the size of the object must be at least 1x1px.

This will alert the callback:

```
var vlc=document.getElementById('vlc');
vlc.addEventListener("MediaPlayerPlaying", function(event) {alert(event);}, false);
vlc.playlist.play();
```

Please note that this is for Firefox & Chrome. Since IE uses ActiveX, another notation is used. For the full documentation, visit https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/